# Seeking the simplest method of updating CKAN linked resources regularly

Tags: datastore, ckan

I'm looking for the simplest method of updating the CKAN DataStore when linked resources are updated. In this case, all resources are linked (no uploads). The resources are csv's and are updated regularly. When updates to the csv files occur the changes don't appear to be auto-magically picked up by CKAN's DataStore. I've attempted to use the ckanapi, but update_resource function only appears to update the metadata. I haven't been able to get it to consistently update the DataStore (thus the Data Explorer View contains outdated information).

Unless there is a simpler method, my preference would be to find a way to programmatically trigger the 'Upload to DataStore' button that can be found on the DataStore tab for a given resource. I've done some fairly extensive searching and haven't been able to find a way to do this yet. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Current version of CKAN is CKAN 2.8.1 with DataStore and DataPusher extensions enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a script using the CKAN API, specifically `datapusher_submit` (see below).

Here's an example python script that I've used in the past.

There's also a [PR open](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/4592) to help document this a little better but hasn't been merged yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
import pprint


# We'll use the package_search function to get all of the resources.
# NOTE: there may be a limit on this in the future and would have to then make multiple calls to collect
# all of the resources. Datasets has a hard-limit of 1000 but defaults to 10. So for now this works, but future issue maybe.
resources_request = urllib2.Request(
    'http://ckan-site.com/api/3/action/resource_search?query=name:')

# Make the HTTP request.
resources_response = urllib2.urlopen(resources_request)
# Make sure it worked
assert resources_response.code == 200

# Use the json module to load CKAN's response into a dictionary.
resources_response_dict = json.loads(resources_response.read())
assert resources_response_dict['success'] is True

results = resources_response_dict['result']['results']

for result in results:
  '''Loop over the resources and submit them to the datastore.
  '''
  try:
    request = urllib2.Request('http://ckan-site.com/api/3/action/datapusher_submit')

    data_dict = {
      "resource_id":result['id']
      }

    data_string = urllib.quote(json.dumps(data_dict))

    request.add_header('Authorization', 'your-token-here')

    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data_string)
    assert json.loads(response.read())['success'] is True
  except:
    # Catch and print any issues and keep going.
    print "resource_id: "  + result['id']
    continue

print "Complete. Datastore is now up to date."
```

Comment: Thanks user3366016. The solution you provided works perfectly in python 2.7.